# what can delete all session files from the session.save_path folder at once

Tags: php, session, joomla

I have bumped with strange server(or cms) behaviour. There is joomla 1.0.15 installed. I noticed it clears session.save_path folder after some time (all session files). I tried to change session.save_path folder to another in htaccess thinking maybe some cron script (directory was successfully changed and session files was created in that new folder) but it happened again and again. Does anybody have ideas what that can be?

```
Joomla 1.0.15
System  Linux n11 3.2.6mtv10 #1 SMP Wed Apr 4 09:28:15 PDT 2012 x86_64 
Configure Command
'./configure''--prefix=/usr/local/php-5.3.13'
'--enable-cli''--enable-cgi'
'--enable-fastcgi''--disable-debug'
'--disable-rpath''--disable-static'
'--with-pic''--with-openssl=/usr'
'--enable-bcmath''--with-bz2'
'--enable-calendar''--enable-ctype'
'--with-curl''--with-db4'
'--with-zlib-dir=/usr''--with-xsl'
'--enable-exif''--enable-ftp'
'--with-gd''--with-ttf'
'--with-mime-magic=/usr/share/file/magic.mime'
'--enable-gd-native-ttf''--with-jpeg-dir=/usr'
'--with-png-dir=/usr''--with-freetype-dir=/usr'
'--with-gettext''--with-iconv'
'--with-imap''--with-kerberos=/usr'
'--with-imap-ssl=/usr''--enable-mbstring'
'--with-mhash''--with-mysql=/usr/bin/mysql_config'
'--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config''--with-pcre-regex=/usr'
'--with-pgsql''--with-pspell=/usr'
'--enable-sockets''--enable-wddx'
'--with-xmlrpc''--with-zlib=/usr'
'--with-pear''--with-layout=GNU'
'--with-ldap''--with-sqlite'
'--enable-pdo''--with-pdo-mysql=/usr'
'--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr''--enable-soap'
'--with-mcrypt''--with-pcre-regex=/usr'
```

Comment: Which operating system/linux distribution are you using? Some package managers know that the OS is using a different session save path and therefore install a cron job to clean it up for comfort. That cron job might run against *your* configuration. So please share.

Comment: Did you verify that the new session save_path was working (the session files showed up in there?)

Comment: Could you successfully change `session.save_path`? That is not clear in your question.

Comment: @hakra Ah yes, sorry. That was successful and new session files was created in that new folder which I set in .htaccess

Comment: Even it might not be actually related, but which operating system are you using? Some more information would actually help to give better suggestions on how to explain what you experience and ask about.

Comment: @hakra updated in description

Comment: *Which* distribution actually? Also if you provide *output* show which commands you used to create it? Or do you enjoy it for others to guess around?

Comment: If could possibly be due to Joomla being a very old version. Try duplicating the Joomla site and updraging it to version 1.5.26 or 2.5.6. Joomla 1.0 is very old and full of bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a server problem, just moved to another hosting